# SAS Addition Shorthand - What are the limitations?

Tags: sas

I know that SAS has a shorthand for arithmetic, allowing users to replace the following clunky statement:

`myclunkyvar = myclunkyvar + 1;`

with this one:

`myclunkyvar + 1;`

However, I'm hesitant to use this because I don't know the limitations and can't find any documentation about it (most search results for SAS shorthand seem to be about list notation).

I'm aware that I could figure some of this out on my own, and I have tested answers to these questions, but I would appreciate a second opinion.

1. What operators does this work for? eg. `*`, `-`, `/` etc.
2. Does it work with multiple variables? eg. `Myvar 1 + Myvar 2 + Myvar 3`?
3. Is there any official documentation about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is called the "Sum statement".

Variable + expression;

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/68024/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1dfiqj146yi2cn1maeju9wo7ijs.htm

Comment: You might want to explain how it's different in the answer (i.e., the `retain` functionality primarily).